# About the using of elasticsearch-php

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

This is the documentation，
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_quickstart.html

The questions are in screenshot below:
[image] 
[image]

**Edit:**

For example,I want to get the search result in this example below,how to write the controller?

view：

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.3.2/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-success-outline" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.3.2/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

route：

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::resource('/search', 'SearchController');

});
```

Controller：

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class SearchController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        //
    }


    public function create()
    {
        //
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Model：Article.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'content'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like they only provided the instructions on how to install composer but you still need to actually require the package with composer by using:

```
composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch
```

If you run composer install it should be autoloaded for you so that you can call it from anywhere. From that point on you can just instantiate the Elasticsearch clientbuilder where you need it.

The "code on the left" is a return response you are getting it is the elasticsearch json converted to a php array.

To actually get up and running you need:

```
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id',
    'body' => ['testField' => 'abc']
];

$response = $client->index($params);
print_r($response);
```

The above should be pretty much what you need, you need to change the params to whatever your settings are and the body to what your search query is.

**Edit**

Looked over the composer.json edit so you need actually need to composer require since it's already in the file. Simply "composer install" is enough.

This is what I whipped up quickly, I tried the index method and it works fine. In this case I still had an elasticsearch server with an index name of "node" and a type of "vacation" this needs to change depending on your personal elasticsearch server. The logical thing here would be to have a type of "user" ofcourse.

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    // the main elasticsearch instance created with the constructor
    protected $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $hosts = [
            // since I am using homestead I have to refer to the ip address of my host machine on which I have installed
            // elasticcsearch, otherwise the default localhost option will point to homestead localhost
            '192.168.178.10:9200'
        ];

        $this->client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts($hosts)->build();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $params = [
            'index' => 'node',
            'type' => 'vacation',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match_all' => []
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $response = $this->client->search($params);
        print_r($response);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $params = [
            'index' => 'node',
            'type' => 'vacation',
            'id' => '1029',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match_all' => []
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $response = $this->client->index($params);
        print_r($response);
    }
}
```

The elasticsearch documentation has all the settings for updating, deleting, indexing and searching neatly documented so just implement those for each resource method.

There is plenty of room for improvement if you want to do it the laravel way and implement this neatly. But this should at least get you going. A better option is to make a serviceprovider for the Elasticsearch client builder and inject it into your UsersController via typehinting but I will leave that up to you.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks very much!  I added some code,could you please give me a demonstration of controller?

Comment: Can't try at the moment but I will try to whip up an installation with elasticsearch tonight so I can provide you some code.